# Not in Query : Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I would like to know how do perform `NOT IN` operation in marklogic they way we perform against rdbms

```
select * from Employee where id not in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I tried `cts:not-in-query` but it takes single instance of single positive & negative queries, how do I pass multiple values like not in (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a range index on `id` (assuming it is an element), you could do:

```
cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('id'), '!=', (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Otherwise you could try:

```
cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('id'), (1,2,3,4,5,6)))
```

HTH!

Comment: I use the latter query all the time.  @grtjn has the right idea.  Since the 2nd parameter can be a sequence, you have unlimited amounts of data you can pass in

Comment: Well, technically not entirely unlimited, but you can stretch it well beyond a million entries if necessary..